# Using document.getElementById more than once messes up If-statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementbyid

In the following loop, I check an input (word.value) against array values:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++){
        for(var i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++){

            if(word.value == dictionary[i][0]){
                word.value = dictionary[i][1];
                console.log(word.value);
                document.getElementById("translation").value = word.value;
            }
            else if(word.value == dictionary[i][1]){
                word.value = dictionary[i][0];
                document.getElementById("translation").value = word.value;
            }

        }
  }
```

The first `if` statement works fine, but if I use `document.getElementById("translation").value = word.value;` second time in the `else if` statement, then the first one wont work properly.

Without the second `getElementById`, the value of `translation` is as it should be, the value in `dictionary[i][1]`, but when I added the second `getElementById`, the value of `translation` became `dictionary[i][0]` instead in the first `if` statement.

Why does using the `getElementById` second time affect the first one?

I need the word.value to be `dictionary[i][1]` in the first and `dictionary[i][0]` in the second.

Full code:

```js
function CheckDictionary() {

  var word = document.getElementById("word");

  /* if(word.value == "auto"){         For debugging purposes.
      word.value = "car";
  }
  else if (word.value == "car"){
      word.value = "auto";
  } */

  // console.log(dictionary.length); // 3
  // console.log(dictionary[0][0]); // 1

  console.log(word.value);

  var dictionary = [
    ["car", "auto"],
    ["phone", "puhelin"],
    ["number", "numero"]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++) {

      if (word.value == dictionary[i][0]) {
        word.value = dictionary[i][1];
        console.log(word.value);
        document.getElementById("translation").value = word.value;
      } else if (word.value == dictionary[i][1]) {
        word.value = dictionary[i][0];
        // document.getElementById("translation").value = word.value; Try with and without this.
      }

    }
  }



}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#FormWrap {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 8px solid gold;
  border-radius: 5px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#FormHead {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: crimson;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px black;
}

.form {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#CheckButton {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: purple;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border-color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

#CheckButton:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

#ResetButton {
  color: purple;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border-color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

#ResetButton:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="task8.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="task8.js"></script>
  <title>Task8</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="FormWrap">
    <!-- Wrapper for Dictionary form -->

    <h1 id="FormHead">Dictionary</h1>
    <!-- Dictionary form heading -->

    <form class="form">
      <!-- Dictionary form -->

      Word:<br>
      <input type="text" id="word" name="Word"><br> Translation:

      <br>
      <input type="text" id="translation" readonly><br><br>

      <input type="button" id="CheckButton" value="Translate" onclick="CheckDictionary()"><br>
      <!-- CheckDictionary button -->

      <input type="reset" id="ResetButton" value="Reset" /> <br><br>
      <!-- Reset the form -->

    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have two elements with the ID `translation`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge No, only one. Both are pointing at the same element.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Please provide sample values for `dictionary` and `word`. Whether or not you use `document.getElementById("translation").value = word.value` at any point in your code should have no bearing on any logic flows

Comment: What's the purpose of the inner loop? You never use `i2` for anything.

Comment: @Barmar if anything, I'd say it's going to guarantee both `if` and `else if` conditions

Comment: @Phil Indeed, I see it now. You want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Perhaps you need to break out of your loops when you find a translation. You almost certainly don't need the inner loop.

Comment: @Barmar no, not really. I'd like to understand why OP is using that inner loop. I'm happy to play the part of the rubber duck in this scenario

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added full HTML and full JavaScript code.

Comment: The first time through the inner loop, you change `word.value` to `dictionary[i][1]`. The second time, the first `if()` test fails, but the second test succeeds, because you changed `word.value`. So it replaces `document.getElementById("translation").value` with that value.

Comment: So the basic problem is that the two times through the `i2` loop are undoing each other. The first time translates from English to Finnish, the second time translates it back from Finnish to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're abusing **word.value** - which is a direct reference to your div with the id word.

```
  if (word.value == dictionary[i][0]) {
    word.value = dictionary[i][1];
    console.log(word.value);
    document.getElementById("translation").value = word.value;
  }
```

With the above you're essentially changing the value in two places - the divs with the id word AND translation.
Instead populate the value of translation directly using the appropriate dictionary entry like

```
  if (word.value == dictionary[i][0]) {
    document.getElementById("translation").value = dictionary[i][1];
  }
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
function CheckDictionary() {

  var word = document.getElementById("word");

  /* if(word.value == "auto"){         For debugging purposes.
      word.value = "car";
  }
  else if (word.value == "car"){
      word.value = "auto";
  } */

  // console.log(dictionary.length); // 3
  // console.log(dictionary[0][0]); // 1

 

  var dictionary = [
    ["car", "auto"],
    ["phone", "puhelin"],
    ["number", "numero"]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++) {
      if (word.value == dictionary[i][0]) {
       
        document.getElementById("translation").value = dictionary[i][1];
      } else if (word.value == dictionary[i][1]) {
         document.getElementById("translation").value = dictionary[i][0];
      }

    }
  }



}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#FormWrap {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 8px solid gold;
  border-radius: 5px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#FormHead {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: crimson;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px black;
}

.form {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#CheckButton {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: purple;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border-color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

#CheckButton:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

#ResetButton {
  color: purple;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  border-color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

#ResetButton:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="task8.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="task8.js"></script>
  <title>Task8</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="FormWrap">
    <!-- Wrapper for Dictionary form -->

    <h1 id="FormHead">Dictionary</h1>
    <!-- Dictionary form heading -->

    <form class="form">
      <!-- Dictionary form -->

      Word:<br>
      <input type="text" id="word" name="Word"><br> Translation:

      <br>
      <input type="text" id="translation" readonly><br><br>

      <input type="button" id="CheckButton" value="Translate" onclick="CheckDictionary()"><br>
      <!-- CheckDictionary button -->

      <input type="reset" id="ResetButton" value="Reset" /> <br><br>
      <!-- Reset the form -->

    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```